# How to create Order in shopify using admin/orders.json?

Tags: json, shopify, postman

I tried to create order using orders.json from postman but it is returning login page in response.
Is there any thing I am missing ? 
I used API URL and order-json as per below. 
API URL :  
https://a472274900fb234caa5934af0301c96f:5ad3266cfabffe98052e261263fa30f6@kathacafetest1.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json

Used following JSON in body

```
{
  "order": {
    "email": "sunil@gmail.com",
    "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
    "send_receipt": true,
    "send_fulfillment_receipt": true,
    "line_items": [
      {
        "variant_id": 34747634826,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

**EDIT**
I used following request in postman

```
POST /admin/orders.json HTTP/1.1
Host: a472274900fb234caa5934af0301c96f:5ad3266cfabffe98052e261263fa30f6@kathacafetest1.myshopify.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ee88ee69-f444-de8c-5eaf-e1a8d3f6d195

{
  "order": {
    "email": "sunil@iprospl.com",
    "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
    "send_receipt": true,
    "send_fulfillment_receipt": true,
    "line_items": [
      {
        "variant_id": 33433316417,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are passing a valid variant-id in the request body. As I have received the following response for your request. 
{
  "errors": {
    "order": [
      "Line items is invalid"
    ],
    "line_items": [
      "Name can't be blank",
      "Price can't be blank",
      "Title can't be blank"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Thanks Savina for your efforts, I checked that variant_id, it is correct. I also tried with another variant_id=33433316417, but the same result.

Comment: Ok, so i gave it another try using variant_id=33433316417. And it worked fine. Can you recheck the request headers?

Comment: In my case only one request header being sent is:- {"Content-Type":"application/json"}

Comment: Did you just give out your API keys?

Comment: I am facing the same issue...

Comment: @MayurShah please review  my answer

Comment: @Sunil Parmar Solved ....thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used https://www.hurl.it/#top to make request.
POST: https://a472274900fb234caa5934af0301c96f:5ad3266cfabffe98052e261263fa30f6@kathacafetest1.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json

Header:
"Content-Type":"application/json"

Body:

```
{
  "order": {
    "email": "sunil@iprospl.com",
    "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
    "send_receipt": true,
    "send_fulfillment_receipt": true,
    "line_items": [
      {
        "variant_id": 33433316417,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And got "order created successfully".